# How to pass function to radio button in a button group created using guide in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, button, radio-button, matlab-guide

I have created a button group with four radio buttons and a push button using guide.

There are four functions, one for each radio button written separately.

1. How do you to call these functions from respective radio buttons.
2. When a push button is pressed, the function associated with the active radio button should execute.

Answer (score 6):

**A solution for the Button Group Callback: SelectionChangeFCN**

Use the *Selection Change* callback property (right click on the Button Group and select *View Callbacks->SelectionChangeFcn*) of the *uipanel*.  The *eventdata* argument contains the handles to the current and previously selected radiobutton. The *eventdata* argument is a structure with the following fields:

- EventName
- OldValue
- NewValue

So, depending on the value of *eventdata.NewValue*; for example

```
function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject,eventdata,handles)
...
newButton=get(eventdata.NewValue,'tag');
switch newButton
     case 'radiobutton1'
         % code for radiobutton 1 here
     case 'radiobutton2'
         % code for radiobutton 2 here
     ...
end
...
```

**A solution for the push button callback**

The callback for your *push button* could have something along the lines of

```
function button1_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
h_selectedRadioButton = get(handles.uipanel1,'SelectedObject');
selectedRadioTag = get(h_selectedRadioButton,'tag')
switch selectedRadioTag
   case 'radiobutton1'

   case 'radiobutton2'
   ...
end
```

I also refer you to the MATLAB documentation for more information on [Handle Graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/bqrw9tj.html) and building [graphical user interfaces](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bqz79mu.html).

Comment: How do you guys always beat me to these???  I was just typing up a solution like this one... :)

Comment: @Azim Hmm... I've never used your approach before, but I have the feeling it's technically the right way to do it. +1 for showing me something new.

Comment: @MatlabDoug Just lucky I noticed the new question in my RSS-reader. It's definitely getting harder to catch unanswered questions.

Comment: @Doresoom thanks. Both approaches should work.  Assigning a callback to each radio button might have advantages as well.

Answer (score 2):

Crash course on GUI's starts... now:

If you're using `guide`, then when you save your figure mygui.fig, the M-file should be automatically generated as mygui.m. Open up mygui.m and enter your code under the radio button callback function. Any variables that you want initialized when you start the program should be defined under the opening function. Make sure you update the handles structure at the end of each callback, with the command guidata(hObject,handles).

For example, if you wanted two mutually exclusive radio buttons (when you select one, the other de-selects, or when you de-select one, the other is selected), enter the following code under their callbacks:

```
function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if get(handles.hObject,'Value')
    set(handles.radiobutton2,'Value',0)
else
    set(handles.radiobutton2,'Value',1)
end
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

and

```
function radiobutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if get(hObject,'Value')
    set(handles.radiobutton1,'Value',0)
else
    set(handles.radiobutton1,'Value',1)
end
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

And initialize radio button one to be selected under the opening function:

```
set(handles.radiobutton1,'Value',1)
set(handles.radiobutton2,'Value',0)
```

Comment: hmmm, just noticed first line of both your functions "handles.b2 = ..." . The _handles_ structure contains the handles for each gui object. So why are you resetting the handle to the object tagged b2? Perhaps you should just have "b2_value = get(...)" instead?

Comment: You're right, I was getting sloppy with my code. Edited to reflect your suggestions.