# calling function in radiobutton group

Tags: matlab, function, button, radio-button, call

with your help, i am now able to call the function for each radio button. however, i get a error message

Reference to non-existent field 'ics_si'

ics_si is my function, which has the following code, i do not know where i am making a mistake

i have created the edit box for user to input the values for bore and stroke. and vdisp is calculated and the result is displayed in the third edit box.

```
function ics_si_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

b = str2double(get(handles.bore,'String'));
s = str2double(get(handles.stroke,'String'));
vdisp = (pi * b * b * s*10^(-3))/4;
set(handles.vdisp,'String',vdisp);
```

this code must be called when i press the first or second radio button. i.e. when the radio button is pressed, it should call the function ics_si, calculate it and display the result.
how to get this.

EDIT by jonas: The question is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624875/how-to-pass-function-to-radio-button-in-a-button-group-created-using-guide-in-mat) question.

Comment: The function looks fine. I guess it is the callback definition that is wrong. When you open the GUI in Guide, and double-click on the radio button, what is the callback that is shown in the property editor?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing how the radio buttons are defined, my guess would be that you have the incorrect name for the function. The callback function is named `ics_si_Callback`, not `ics_si`.