# How to use effectively radio buttons in a button group MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing, user-interface

I have 5 different filters as 5 different radio buttons in MATLAB GUI. I made them into a button group and now when i click the each button the noise image is shown through the axes. But i want to set the button group in such a way to show only one filter (one image). So, I followed this 
([How to pass function to radio button in a button group created using guide in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624875/how-to-pass-function-to-radio-button-in-a-button-group-created-using-guide-in-ma)) which is given here at stackoverflow. But how do we "set" image in an axes.
I have attached the figure of my GUI.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fZ5V.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "set" the image in an `axes` object using the normal plotting commands.  Suppose the variable `ax` holds the handle to the axes object you want to draw on, you could write the following:

```
axes(ax);      % Select the chosen axes as the current axes
cla;           % Clear the axes
imagesc(im);   % Now draw whatever you want - for example, an image.
```

Incidentally, in GUIDE you can get usually get the axes handle using the `handles` argument passed to all callbacks. So for example, if your axes are called `axes1`, your Button Group callback might look like this:

```
function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    ax = handles.axes1;  % Get handle to axes
    axes(ax);            % Select the chosen axes as the current axes
    cla;                 % Clear the axes
    imagesc(rand(50) );  % Now draw
```